# Don't queue fadeTo(), fadeIn()/fadeOut()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, queuing

I have the following animations:

```
$('#id').animate({'margin-top': 100, 'margin-left': 100}, {queue: false, duration: 1000});
$('#id2').fadeTo(1000, 1);
```

this seems to be queuing, how can i make sure that fadeTo() doesn't queue?

Comment: It is not queueing for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/Z8Rs3/ Both animations are started at the same time. Or do you mean that *repeated* calling of these animations queue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#id2').stop().fadeTo(1000, 1);
```

Comment: this also seemed to do the trick, but used my original method as that seemed to work

Answer (score -2):

Move the opacity change into the animation.

```
$('#id').css({opacity:0}).show().animate({marginTop: 100, marginLeft: 100, opacity:1}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vcBPR/

Comment: Except for the fact that the opacity change is on #id2, a different element.

Comment: Yeah I thought it was an literal error with the id's as jQuery does not queue anything cross nodes itself.