# JQuery fade in while sliding down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The script below does not fire the **slideDown** and **fadeTo** at the same time. It does not fade in until the slide down finishes.

```
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var obj = $("#example");
        obj.slideDown(450);
        obj.fadeTo(450,1);
    });
    </script>
```

How can I simultaneously slide the object down while also fading it in?

Also, the object is just a normal **div**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251300/how-to-run-two-jquery-animations-simultaneously

Comment: This could always be done with css too. The more you can do without js the better.  https://jsfiddle.net/796og4z5/1/

Just add/remove a class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `slideDown` and `fadeTo`, both of these calls are added to a queue(`fx` queue) and is executed one after another.

You can use [.animate()](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) to animate a set of css properties

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj = $("#example");
    obj.animate({
        opacity: 1,
        height: 'show'
    }, 450);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var obj = $("#example");
  obj.animate({
    opacity: 1,
    height: 'show'
  }, 450);
});
```

```css
#example {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: pre-line;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj = $("#example");
    obj.slideDown(450);
    obj.fadeTo(450, 1);
});
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    obj.slideDown({duration: 450, queue: false});
    obj.stop().fadeTo(1000, 1);
```

[Don't queue fadeTo(), fadeIn()/fadeOut()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640929/dont-queue-fadeto-fadein-fadeout)